# Reservoir sampling with a computationally expensive weight function

Tags: sampling, approximation, resampling, weighted-sampling

I have a large dataset, and I want to obtain a small sample of it of size K, weighted by a function f(x) which is expensive to compute (I'm ok computing it O(K) times, but not too much more). Suppose I also know some cheap-to-compute functions lo(x) <= f(x) <= hi(x).

What are the methods to perform such sampling?

Two things come to mind:

- Perform a preliminary (over-)sampling pass weighted by hi(x), and sample from there "for real" using f(x). In this case, I'm wondering how much should I oversample?
- Use reservoir sampling and use hi(x) to cut off the computation of some f(x) - i.e. if rand()^(1/hi(x)) < min, then simply skip x; if not, then consider it the usual way using the expensive f(x). In this case, I'm wondering if I can/should reuse the same random number for cutoff vs. actual sampling, and whether this is in general statistically sound.

Comment: Unless you're repeatedly creating samples, the expense of calculating f(x) shouldn't be that big a problem. Even if it takes an hour to create your sample, you only need to do it once.

Comment: What do you mean by "sample of size K, weighted by a function f(x)" ? Can you select the same item repeatedly? Suppose N=3, K=2, f(x1)=100, f(x2)=10, f(x3)=1.  What are the chances of selecting (1,1),(2,2),(3,3), (1,2),(2,3),(1,3) ?

Comment: @Hong I am repeatedly creating samples. A user can request to get a sample of the dataset (which is constantly changing) and they would like to see items sampled proportionally to f(x). I would like the user's request to be processed quickly - I can afford one pass over the dataset, but I cannot afford to call f() on every item.

Comment: @user31264 I need a sample without replacement. I just need a modification of weighted reservoir sampling where I don't need to compute the weight for every item. I have currently decided to to a first pass weighted by hi(x) to get a sample of size S, with U >> S >> K (U is size of the whole dataset) and use rejection sampling to subsample from there using f(x).

Comment: Suppose N=3, K=2, f(x1)=100, f(x2)=10, f(x3)=1. What are the chances of selecting (1,2),(2,3),(1,3) ?

Comment: @user31264 The same as whatever weighted reservoir sampling would give me - I'm just looking for a way to speed up weighted reservoir sampling. However, solving the corresponding system of linear equations (denote the chances of selecting these by a, b, c where a+b+c=1; then a+c : a+b : b+c = 100:10:3) gives me a negative solution for b... weird.

Comment: Simulating weighted sampling with replacement gives me (1,2):(2,3):(1,3) = 112/1111 : 211/1111 : 10. So that's what we should get, however this doesn't give 1:2:3 = 100:10:1.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain that this is what you're asking, but a while ago I wrote [a series of posts](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/95845-Generating-Samples-From-Custom-Probability-Distributions-I) explaining how to do envelope rejection sampling while doing only very few evaluations of the probability density function. It is developed in a couple of stages, and for the last stage you have quite a few restrictions, but the initial stages sound like they apply.

Comment: Thanks Erik! Great posts! (apologies for replying so late - I've stepped aside from the problem where I needed this for a while) However, they assume that the problem statement is "generate a sample", rather than "select a sample from an existing set or bounded stream". Currently looks like my best option is bullet 2 from my question. Do you think it is sound?

Comment: @jkff One thing I'm confused about is: do you know the sum of f(x) over all x?